Playwright can annotations be seen in Azure pipeline test reports
I'm using annotations to document when a test should fail because of a known bug. How can I get the information to show in Azure pipeline reports, in a similar way to how they are shown in html reports within the annotation section?
testInfo.fail(true, "Bug 1234");
Sample playwright report
Followed playwrights Azure pipeline documentation
